# Is there a way of detecting whether Microsoft Teams is in use before running an update script?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm deploying a script across my organization to keep software patched with our chocolatey repo, I'm including tests so it doesn't upgrade applications that are currently running on workstations however I'm struggling to detect whether Teams is actively being used by the user or just running in the background. Here's what I've got so far:

```
# First attempt - Check if the Teams process is running and if not, upgrade it
$teams = Get-Process | Where {$_.ProcessName -Like "*teams*"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (-Not $teams) {
    Write-Host "Teams not running, upgrading..."
    choco upgrade microsoft-teams.install -y
}

# Second attempt - Upgrade Teams if there are less than 5 running processes
if ((get-process -ea silentlycontinue teams).count -gt 5) {
    Write-Host "Teams running, aborting"
    exit 1
} else {
    Write-Host "Updating Teams"
    choco upgrade microsoft-teams.install -y
}
```

They both don't work reliably as Teams is often running with multiple processes even when it's not in active use, is there any way of telling whether it's present in the Taskbar/minimised to the tray that would be a good indication of whether an update would interrupt the user?

Comment: are you aware of : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-client-update

It appears that the choco package is actually installing the VDI package for all your end-users , rather than the standard Teams client.

Comment: Note that Teams for VDI has a number of restrictions documented here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-for-vdi#known-issues-and-limitations

Answer (score 0):

There is no such cmdlet available and provided by Microsoft. I have also gone through other docs and its not there.